# How to resize div and contents for any screen size?

Tags: css, html, resize

I am working on ryan.tylerdetmers.com/cmd

I want the div in the middle to resize to fit peoples screen sizes. So whether you're on an iphone or a desktop, it fits it properly. I also want the contents within that div to resize.

I am not sure if I have to do something to each individual piece, or if there is something out there that would do this for me in an easier fashion.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: what have you worked till now? Post your initial work here.

Comment: You may be looking for responsive site can be achieved by using media queries - http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps

Comment: Quite easy with Bootstrap. Did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

This is called responsive design. With this, your website adjusts it's size according to the device that opened it.

First you have to include this in your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
```

More about [viewport here.](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/)

And in your CSS, some of the common media queries:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Here you should set what size you want your div to be 
when viewed on smartphone */
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Full list of media queries [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the viewport units specified in CSS3, first you have to set the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then in CSS (without using media queries) set the width of the div or whatever element you have to 100vw (i.e. 100% of the viewport width), and you can then set child elements as percentages to retain responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

make

```
style="height:66.67vh;"
```

It should resize the window when your original window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate screen height & width and  set height and width for your DIV.

```
//Calculate screen height and width
var winWidth=$( window ).width();

positionFromLeft=(winWidth - divWidth)/2;
positionFromRight=(winWidth - divWidth)/2;
```

This should work for all resolutions.
Now you can set div position from left and right.Now your div will appear in center.